# IIS7 set up issue

Tags: ssl, iis

Not sure if SU or Server Fault is a better place to ask, but I'm setting up IIS7 with SSL on a Windows 2008 VPS

I followed [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates)

I complete the tutorial but the site will not start(Shows the stopped icon). Clicking start results with the following message:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I Google, SO post suggest I use http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015

The suggestion is

```
At the command prompt, type the following command:
netstat -ano
Note For more information about the Netstat.exe utility, type the following command at the command prompt:
netstat /?
If the ports are not being used, you must examine the
ListenOnlyList
registry subkey on the computer that is running IIS. To do, this follow these steps:

    Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
    In Registry Editor, locate the following registry subkey:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\ListenOnlyList
```

So, 443 does not show any IP address so I guess it is not in use?

[image]

I tried this (to find the ListenOnlyList), but, I don't have ListenOnlyList as an option on my W2008 web server.

Removing the SSL binding fixes the problem (in the sense, the website starts) but, I need the SSL working too!

What can I do to get IIS to work with SSL on this site?

Comment: What process is PID 1948?  When you disable SSL binding in IIS, does NetStat still show something listening on 443?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, your question suggests my understanding is incorrect. I didn't think any thing was listening on 443? However, I'm now realising it does and what I need to do. SVN (Subversion) is on pID 1948... I assume this simply means they are conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in Netstat with a local IP of 0.0.0.0 in listening mode means it's listening on all IPs that are assigned to the machine.

Stop IIS -- If something is still listening on 443, then use the PID reported by Netstat to determine which process is listening on port 443.  Once you know which service/program it is, reconfigure it to use a different port (or just disable that service -- your choice :) ).

Comment: I thought 0.0.0.0 actually meant "invalid" IP address. However, as I suspect you know, you're right! Subversion was using 443, I changed it and IIS is now more than happy with my site starting. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. :)